# write las file to directory in python

Tags: python

I think this should be simple and that I am just missing something. I read the documentation on this. (see website below)
I am just trying to write this file to somewhere on my directory. (ie. C:\Users)

I always seem to have trouble at this point haha. 
I am using a a package to read/write .las files. It is great. I just need to save the .las to my directory. Any help is appreciated.

http://pythonhosted.org/lasio/usage.html#example-ipython-notebooks

This writes it to the console. how do I write it to the "C:\Users\"

```
import sys
l.write(sys.stdout, version=2.0, fmt="%10.5g")
```

I tried this but it does not work

```
l.write('C:/Users/Test.las', version=2.0, fmt="%10.5g")
```

here is the issue.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-64d516a834ff> in <module>()
      2 #exportfile = l.write(sys.stdout, version=2.0, fmt="%10.5g")
      3 
----> 4 l.write('C:/Users/Test.las', version=2.0, fmt="%10.5g")

C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lasio\las.py in write(self, file_object, version, wrap, STRT, STOP, STEP, fmt)
    175         '''
    176         writer.write(self, file_object, version=version, wrap=wrap,
--> 177                      STRT=STRT, STOP=STOP, STEP=STEP, fmt=fmt)
    178 
    179     def get_curve(self, mnemonic):

C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lasio\writer.py in write(las, file_object, version, wrap, STRT, STOP, STEP, fmt)
    129     lines.append('~ASCII '.ljust(60, '-'))
    130 
--> 131     file_object.write('\n'.join(lines))
    132     file_object.write('\n')
    133 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: `sys.stdout` is a *file handle*, so that may be why your own attempt - feeding it a simple string - failed. (Note that "it doesn't work" may be an accurate description but nevertheless is quite useless. No error messages, or anything?) Look for a way to create a file handle in Python's io libraries.

Comment: `with open('Test.las', 'w') as f: l.write(f, version ...)`

Comment: Thanks, and yes. I I know it is not a good description. I just knew it was a simple fix. I always struggle at the output of files though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file first and write to the open file object:

```
with open('C:/Users/Test.las', 'w') as fobj:
    l.write(fobj, version=2.0, fmt="%10.5g")
```